# Waiting for an Event

Tags: java, multithreading, events, blackberry

I'm trying to implement a Bluetooth functionality class for a Blackberry. But I got stuck in connecting the device..

I made a simple *MainScreen* that connect, disconnect (for now). The bluetooth functionality is implmemented in another class that *implmements BluetoothSerialPortListener*.

When i select the "connect" option, it runs this code:

```
connect(BluetoothSerialPortInfo info){
    port = new BluetoothSerialPort(info, BluetoothSerialPort.BAUD_57600,....,this);
```

When the connection protocol finishes, the function `deviceConnected(boolean success)` is executed by the Blackberry, with a `boolean` that has the result of the connection (true if it is connected, and false if not). I wanted to check for this boolean value before return from the `connect(BluetoothSerialPortInfo info)` method, so i put a `wait(1000)` in the it, and a `notify()` in `deviceConnected(boolean success)`.

The **problem** is that both functions or methods are executed by the same thread, and when the `wait(1000)` is made, the timeout finishes, and then the *deviceConnected* function is executed...

I tried to run the *connect* method in a separate Thread, and it worked, but then i couldn't access to the *MainScreen* objects to notify the success or not of the connection (and even if i could, i would prefer not doing it).

I would love to know how to run the Listener methods in a separate Thread, so they could be executed even if the main thread is busy.

Thanks in advance.

(I hope i explaned myself...)

**EDIT**
More explanation, in case i didn't explained it well:

The thing is, i do `connect(info)`, and if i try to do for example Thread.sleep(10000), the thread will sleep 10 seconds, and after that time, the deviceConnected method is called, and then can i see the answer. Watever i try to do in the method that runs `connect(info)` just postpone the execution of `deviceConnected`. That is why i would run the Listener methods (`deviceConnected` as example) in another Thread, so it can be executed while i wait in the method `connect(info)` for the answer....

**EDIT: CODE:**

The connect method:

```
public int BT_ConnectDevice(BluetoothSerialPortInfo info)
{
    if (info==null) return(0x4F);

    try
    {

        _port = new BluetoothSerialPort(info, BluetoothSerialPort.BAUD_57600, BluetoothSerialPort.DATA_FORMAT_PARITY_NONE | BluetoothSerialPort.DATA_FORMAT_STOP_BITS_1 | BluetoothSerialPort.DATA_FORMAT_DATA_BITS_8, BluetoothSerialPort.FLOW_CONTROL_NONE, 1024, 1024, this);
        return(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return(0x3F);
    }
}
```

The method executed by the Listener:

```
public void deviceConnected(boolean success)
{
    this._bDeviceIsConnected=success;
}
```

I tried to add in the *connect* method something like:

```
synchronized(lock){
    try{
        lock.wait(10000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    if (_bDeviceIsConnected) return (0);
}
return(0x3F);
```

And of course add the `lock.notify()` in the deviceConnected. But as long as i wait, the deviceConnected is executed **after** the *return* from BT_ConnectDevice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest a re-imagining of your system design?  Why do need the connect() method to be blocking?

My suggestion would be to redesign such that the code that calls connect() understands that it is a non-blocking call and then have your listener kick-off the necessary next step(s) once the connection is established.

You could try something like this pseudo-code:

```
public void fieldChanged(Field f, int c) {
    if (f == myConnectButton) {
        connect(...);
    }
}

private class MyBluetoothConnectionListener ... {
    public void deviceConnected(boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            bluetoothConnectionEstablished();
        } else {
            bluetoothConnectionFailed();
        }
    }
}

private void bluetoothConnectionEstablished() {
    // TODO - put your logic here for what to do when the connection succeeds
}

private void bluetoothConnectionFailed() {
    // TODO - put your logic here for what to do when the connection fails
}
```

Comment: mmmm. I would love to do what you say, but i don't really know how... 

The main problem that i have, is that the Threads seems to work in a different way in Blackberry than in other OS. I have made something similar with the Threads in Windows and Linux, and it did work.

Anyway, if i could set the connection as you say, please, explain me a little more what do you mean...
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Scott, thanks again. The Listener part is already built. The problem is to know in the "connect(...)" the value of "success".

I don't quite understand what does the fieldChanged thing do. I think that in a while i will be able to post some code. I have it in another computer...

Comment: okay, I guess I am questioning the base assumption that the connect() method must know when a connection has been established.  For example, try making two methods connect() and connectPart2().  Then put the code that was going to wait for a connection to be established in connectPart2() and execute that from your listener.

Comment: @Vic, given the code that you have posted, I would recommend changing your BT_ConnectDevice to something like `public void BT_ConnectDevice(...) throws MyBluetoothConnectionException`.  Then you throw exceptions instead of returning in your error scenarios.  Finally, in the code that is calling BT_ConnectDevice, you will have to change the assumption that a connection is available when BT_ConnectDevice returns, and instead continue your process from the `deviceConnected()` function.

Comment: Hi @Scott. Thank you very much.. I will try that tomorrow morning. I also thought that, continue the process from the `deviceConnected()` function. I just tried the other possibility because it seems more logic to me. But it seems there is no way.. As i said, i will try what you say about throw a Exception, it seems a very good idea. Thanks! Finally: Should i mark it as an answer or would you prefer to write it in another "answer"?

Comment: If it were me, I'd just make this the answer.

Answer (score 0):

could you not just run the connection in a while loop?

```
    while(!success){
    // try to connect
    }
```

hopefully, it'll keep trying before you time-out.

with regards to the multithreading [here's a link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html) that'll show you a tutorial on how its done server side.
Remember the implements runnable on the class and to run() each thread to start it.

hope this helps.

Comment: As i understand it, you ask why i didn do something like:
    while(!success){
        connect(info);
    }

I think that will not help. Maybe i didn't explain it very well.. I will try to explain again (i will add it later to the main question) and then answer..
The thing is, i do `connect(info)`, and if i try to do for example `Thread.sleep(10000)`, the thread will sleep 10 seconds, and after that time, the `deviceConnected` method is called, and then can i see the answer.

If i do what you say, `deviceConnected` will never be executed...

Comment: Whenever I have made a server to client connection before, I've opened the connection and it has waited for the client to connect.
After doing a little reading on bluetooth connections, i found this;


        `//open server url
        StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open( connectionString );
        //Wait for client connection
        StreamConnection connection=streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen ();`

it should open the connection and wait for the client to connect

Comment: Thanks again. Two things: 
1) I shall initiate the connection as a client, not as a Server.
2) I am trying to implement the functionality without the Listener, and am trying with this "Connector.open(string);", but the Blackberry doesn't allow me to execute a blocking instruction in the thread... :(

Comment: as far as i am aware you still need a listener to run first, regardless of whether the client or server would be initiating the communication.

Comment: Yes, of course. I need a listener. But the listener that comes in the RIM package doesn't work as i need. The problem is that i execute the "connect" method, and it try to connect. But i cannot wait until i can see if the connection was successfull or not.. I have tried 3 or 4 ways, but none seems to work.. It seems that i have to connect, and expect that the connection is made. But i have no way to know the result. Thanks again for your time... If you think of anything, please tell me.